# Runtime Error 3075 MS Access VBA when running query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vba

I'm trying to run this query via VBA code and I'm getting "Run -Time 3075 error". I tried to reorganize in diferent ways but its not working out. It runs fine as a query.

Here is the original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TB_Vendor.Vend_name, TB_POLine.ord_no, IIf(IsNull([cus_name]),StrConv([bill_to_name],3),StrConv([cus_name],3)) AS Customer, TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2, IIf(IsNumeric([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt]) And IsNull([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt]),DateSerial(Left$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],4),Mid$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],5,2),Right$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],2)),IIf(IsNumeric([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt]) And IsNull([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt]),DateSerial(Left$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],2)),Null)) AS [Request Date], DateSerial(Left$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],2)) AS [Order Date], IIf([TB_POLine].[promise_dt]<>0,DateSerial(Left$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],2)),Null) AS [Promise Date], TB_POHeader.user_name, TB_POHeader.ord_status, TB_POLine.move_to_loc, IIf([vchr_no]=0,"Received",IIf([vchr_no]>0,"Vouchered",IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[TB_POLine Query].[Pro Date])<=0,"Late","On Time"))) AS Status, TB_POHeader.cmt_2, TB_POHeader.cmt_3, TB_POHeader.cmt_1
FROM [TB_POLine Query] RIGHT JOIN (CS_Receivings RIGHT JOIN (CS_CLIENTOENTRY1 RIGHT JOIN (CS_CLIENTOENTRY RIGHT JOIN (TB_POHeader RIGHT JOIN (TB_Vendor RIGHT JOIN TB_POLine ON TB_Vendor.vend_no = TB_POLine.vend_no) ON TB_POHeader.ord_no = TB_POLine.ord_no) ON CS_CLIENTOENTRY.[Ticket #] = TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2) ON CS_CLIENTOENTRY1.[Ticket #] = TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2) ON CS_Receivings.ord_no = TB_POLine.ord_no) ON [TB_POLine Query].ord_no = TB_POLine.ord_no
GROUP BY TB_Vendor.Vend_name, TB_POLine.ord_no, IIf(IsNull([cus_name]),StrConv([bill_to_name],3),StrConv([cus_name],3)), TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2, IIf(IsNumeric([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt]) And IsNull([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt]),DateSerial(Left$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],4),Mid$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],5,2),Right$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],2)),IIf(IsNumeric([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt]) And IsNull([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt]),DateSerial(Left$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],2)),Null)), DateSerial(Left$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],2)), IIf([TB_POLine].[promise_dt]<>0,DateSerial(Left$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],2)),Null), TB_POHeader.user_name, TB_POHeader.ord_status, TB_POLine.move_to_loc, IIf([vchr_no]=0,"Received",IIf([vchr_no]>0,"Vouchered",IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[TB_POLine Query].[Pro Date])<=0,"Late","On Time"))), TB_POHeader.cmt_2, TB_POHeader.cmt_3, TB_POHeader.cmt_1
HAVING (((DateSerial(Left$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],2)))>#1/1/2014#) AND ((TB_POHeader.ord_status)<>"C"))
ORDER BY TB_POLine.ord_no DESC;
```

And VBA Code I'm using

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSql As String
Dim cns As QueryDef
Dim teste As String
Dim teste2 As String

Dim RstSql As QueryDef

'Set RstSql = Application.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Consulta1")
Set db = CurrentDb()

StrSql = "SELECT DISTINCT TB_Vendor.Vend_name, TB_POLine.ord_no, IIf(IsNull([cus_name]),StrConv([bill_to_name],3),StrConv([cus_name],3)) AS Customer, TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2, IIf(IsNumeric([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt]) And, " & _
"IsNull([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt]),DateSerial(Left$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],4),Mid$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],5,2),Right$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt],2)),IIf(IsNumeric([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt]) And, " & _
"IsNull([CS_CLIENTOENTRY].[request_dt]),DateSerial(Left$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([CS_CLIENTOENTRY1].[ord_dt],2)),Null)), " & _
"AS [Request Date], DateSerial(Left$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POHeader].[ord_dt],2)) AS [Order Date], " & _
"IIf([TB_POLine].[promise_dt]<>0,DateSerial(Left$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],4),Mid$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],5,2),Right$([TB_POLine].[promise_dt],2)),Null) AS [Promise Date], TB_POHeader.user_name, TB_POHeader.ord_status, TB_POLine.move_to_loc, TB_POHeader.cmt_2, TB_POHeader.cmt_3, TB_POHeader.cmt_1, " & _
"FROM TB_POLine Query] RIGHT JOIN (CS_Receivings RIGHT JOIN (CS_CLIENTOENTRY1 RIGHT JOIN (CS_CLIENTOENTRY RIGHT JOIN (TB_POHeader RIGHT JOIN (TB_Vendor RIGHT JOIN TB_POLine ON TB_Vendor.vend_no = TB_POLine.vend_no) ON TB_POHeader.ord_no = TB_POLine.ord_no) ON CS_CLIENTOENTRY.[Ticket #] = TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2) ON CS_CLIENTOENTRY1.[Ticket #] = TB_POLine.user_def_fld_2) ON CS_Receivings.ord_no = TB_POLine.ord_no) ON [TB_POLine Query].ord_no = TB_POLine.ord_no "

If Not IsNull(Comb1.Value) Then
    teste = teste & " [CS_POStatus].[user_name] = '" & Comb1.Value & "'"
End If

If teste = " WHERE " Then
    teste = " WHERE TB_CS_POStatus.[ser_name]='Null';"
Else
    teste = teste '& ";"

End If

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSql & teste)

Set RstSql = Application.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("CS_POStatus")
RstSql.SQL = StrSql & teste & " ORDER BY CS_POStatus.ord_no;"

If teste = ";" Then
    MsgBox ("Please select at least one search criteria.")
Else
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("There are no results for this search")
    End If

    Lista8.Requery

    Me.Refresh

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I rarely comment on code but I'm sorry to have to say that this code it truly horrendous and you shouldn't be surprised that you're getting errors you can't fix.

There are many kinds of wrong here, the biggest one being that this SQL query is impossible to read.

Having said that:

- Your first line of SQL VBA end with `And,`, that `,` doesn't make sense.
- Same issue with the second line.
- Your third line also ends with an extra `,` which causes the `AS [Request Date]` on the next line to be on its own, which will also generate an error.
- Your fourth line also ends with an extra `,`. Since ti's followed by `FROM` on the next line, you will also get an error message.
- Your sixth line misses a `[`: `FROM TB_POLine Query]` should be `FROM [TB_POLine Query]`.

You said that the queries were the same, but they are not. The query that you say works has a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause that the VBA query doesn't have...

You have to seriously consider being more meticulous:

- Format your SQL, even in VBA. Use something like [SQL Pretty Printer](http://www.dpriver.com/) or some other free software or online service to help you.
- clean up your code: your code for building `teste` is probably not going to work in all the various cases you are trying to check.
- When testing VBA-build SQL code, put a breakpoint at the point where the SQL is passed to `OpenRecordset`, print it to the immediate window and copy it into a new SQL Query to check where the Query editor complains. You would have found your errors if you had at least tried to debug the resulting VBA SQL into the Query editor.

All I can predict, is that if you continue writing code like that, you're going to be in a lot of pain for a long time, and I wouldn't be surprised if some of what seems to work, actually doesn't work properly.

Write code that anyone can read.
At least write code that *you* can read...